# Proof by induction for a sequence, given $a_1$ and $a_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, induction

Question:  prove by induction that this statement holds.
Define  the sequence $(a_{k}),  k∈\mathbb N ,$
by $a_1 = 2, a_2 = 5 $
and
$a_{k+2} = 5a_{k+1} − 6a_{k} $ for all $k≥1$. Then $a_{k} =2^{n−1} +3^{n-1}$ for all $n≥1 $.

What I did was find the base case -- $ P(1)=2 $ -- holds
Then made an assumption that $P(k)$ holds.  Thus we can assume $P(k+1)$ and I got that
$= 5×2^{k−1} +5×3^{k−1} −3×2^{k−1} −2×3^{k−1}.$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I’m new to this so I’m not sure how to edit. This to make it look exactly like the question- any help with formatting will help me too- thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: k not n, and k is incorrect in the exponents when you try to do the induction
$$a_{k+2} = 5a_{k+1} − 6a_{k}$$
$$a_{k+2} = 5×2^{k} +5×3^{k} −6×2^{k−1} −6×3^{k−1}$$
$$a_{k+2} = 10×2^{k−1} +15×3^{k−1} −6×2^{k−1} −6×3^{k−1}$$
$$a_{k+2} = 4×2^{k−1} +9×3^{k−1}$$
$$a_{k+2} = 2^{k+2} +3^{k+2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $P(n)$ is $a_n=2^{n-1}+3^{n-1}$.

Base:  $P(1):  a_1=2=2^0+3^0$, $P(2):  a_2=5=2^1+3^1$.

Now assuming $P(k)$ and $P(k+1)$, we have

$P(k+2):  a_{k+2}=5a_{k+1}-6a_k=5(2^k+3^k)-6(2^{k-1}+3^{k-1})$

$=(5-3)2^{k}+(5-2)3^{k}=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1}.$